# How to open jupyter nookbooks in docker container?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have the following containers when running `docker-compose ps`:

```
 Name                    Command             State           Ports          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rainmaker_db_1       docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld   Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp 
rainmaker_python_1   python -u /app/run.py         Up      0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp
```

I want to run jupyther inside the container rainmaker_python_1, so I am running the following command:

```
docker-compose exec python jupyter notebook --allow-root
```

Then I get the following output:

```
[I 23:03:19.168 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /app
[I 23:03:19.168 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 23:03:19.168 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=35ff0fa9ec171204dbd7542d9c493c760055de24e1b7af18
[I 23:03:19.168 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 23:03:19.169 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 23:03:19.169 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=35ff0fa9ec171204dbd7542d9c493c760055de24e1b7af18
```

However, if I copy and paste the link `http://localhost:8888/?token=35ff0fa9ec171204dbd7542d9c493c760055de24e1b7af18` I get that the site cannot be reached. Then I tried:

```
http://localhost:5000/?token=35ff0fa9ec171204dbd7542d9c493c760055de24e1b7af18
```

But I get the following:

[image]

I wanna be able to execute the jupyter notebook, so please I hope somebody could help me. I have almost no experience with Docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the default port number for Jupyter notebooks is 8888. You can see this in the console output when your Docker container is launching Jupyter.

Either change your port mappings in your Docker compose file, like I do below, or look to see if there's an environmental variable you can set in the Docker compose file to make a Docker / Jupyter to run on the port you do have open (5000).

Below, the  Docker compose section sets up a Node server on port 8888 (thanks copypasta) , but should provide enough example to change yours) - really the only important line is the ports line.

```
version: '2'
services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
       dockerfile: DockerFile
     ports:
       - "8888:8888"
```

Comment: I am using this for a Flask application, so I have this `ports:
            - "5000:5000"` Could I add more ports?

Comment: Yup, just add another line to the ports section, just like the first

Comment: I just tried what you have suggested, but I am getting `GET http://localhost:8888/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Comment: Did you `docker-compose down`? You may have to even `docker compose down --rmi=local` to completely remove the container, so it's rebuilt with the right port numbers????

Comment: I run both `docker-compose down`, and then `docker-compose up -d --build`, the log of one of the containers is: `* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
172.19.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2017 17:55:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -`. Then I run `docker container exec -it rainmaker_python_1 /bin/bash`, and inside the container I run `jupyter notebook --allow-root`, and it is still not working.

Comment: I wonder if you need to figure out how to get jupyter to host from 0.0.0.0 vs localhost...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142411/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-ryanwilcox).